# How to detect if show more is enabled for a div?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend

Iv got a very simple question but for some reason I just cant come up with how this is suppose to be done within vue.

I have a div on my website which loops an array using v-for to show different shop articles. I would like that when people click the "Show more" link in that div, that it show's all the items that are in that shop article.

This is the process:

- Person loads the page so I send an axios request to the API to get all the shop articles
- Axios returns an array of all shop article objects
- The page displays each article in it's own div and if someone clicks "Show More" it should only show more for the article they clicked on

How I would currently fix this is by looping through all shop article objects and adding a variable "show" which can be true or false. But this seems like the wrong way to do it. How would I go about achieving this the right way?

**EDIT: Adding sample code**
So first i call the api to get all articles

```
fetchArticles: function() {
                var self = this;
                axios.get('/api/shop/articles/crowdfunding').then(function(response) {
                    self.articles = response.data;
                }).catch(function() {
                    alert('An error occured on the page.')
                });
            },
```

Next it get's displayed in the div:

```
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4" v-for="article in articles">
                            <div class="card">
                                <img class="card-img-top" src="/assets/images/valar/mountain_desert_286x180.png" alt="Card image cap">
                                <div class="card-body" style="text-align: center;">
                                    <h5>{{article.title}}</h5>
                                    <p>{{article.description}}</p>
                                    <a href="#" @click.prevent="????">Show Items</a>
                                    <div class="row" v-if="?????">
                                        <div class="col-4" v-for="item in article.items">
                                            <DisplayItem :item_id="item.item_id" :key="item.id"></DisplayItem>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <button class="nk-btn nk-btn-color-white link-effect-4 float-right ready" @click.prevent="buyArticle(article.id)">Buy (${{article.price}})</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

What i would like to do is loop all the values in "articles" and add a variable "display" being true or false, then add @click which set's the display variable on that array index to true/false. But it seems like a very inefficient way of doing this because i would have to loop all values.

Comment: What is your current code? Include it in the question.

Comment: There's no code at the moment, because I can't think of how to do this correctly :/ But i will write some sample code now and update the post in like 5 minutes!

Comment: Do it "incorrectly", but do it :). You've got to start somewhere and you've got to try. You'd be amazed by how much can you squeeze out of yourself when you bust your head on the problem long enough.

Comment: Btw, it doesn't seem wrong way to do it, as I see it. In plain JS, you would "listen" for a click on each individual article and then manipulate it the way you want to. I'm not so experienced with Vue, but I believe you can use `@click` to achieve something similar.

Comment: @NemanjaGlumac Yeah id imagine just doing @click="article[INDEX].display = true" but how would i add the display variable to each object in the array without looping them all and adding this variable? Unless you are correct and this is the actual way to do it.

Comment: @NemanjaGlumac Iv added the code i have now :)

Comment: If that key is not present you can treat it as false. I believe it works this way by default in Vue. Add the key only after user clicks display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-existant property will be treated as `false` by Vue. So, no need to put false for all objects. Just set `show_items` to true for that object once user clicks on it.

```
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4" v-for="article in articles">
                        <div class="card">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="/assets/images/valar/mountain_desert_286x180.png" alt="Card image cap">
                            <div class="card-body" style="text-align: center;">
                                <h5>{{article.title}}</h5>
                                <p>{{article.description}}</p>
                                <a href="#" @click.prevent="article.show_items = true">Show Items</a>
                                <div class="row" v-if="article.show_items">
                                    <div class="col-4" v-for="item in article.items">
                                        <DisplayItem :item_id="item.item_id" :key="item.id"></DisplayItem>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <button class="nk-btn nk-btn-color-white link-effect-4 float-right ready" @click.prevent="buyArticle(article.id)">Buy (${{article.price}})</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Sometimes, just setting a new property may not be reactive (as the property is not monitored by Vue). If above doesn't work, you can use this.$set(object, key, value):

```
@click.prevent="makeItemsVisible(article)">Show Items</a>


makeItemsVisible(article){
    this.$set(article, 'show_items', true);
}
```

Refer Vue reactivity, and why sometimes we need to call `set` explicitly:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html